# <pre> tag making browsers close paragraphs

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, opera

I'm having an issue with the HTML below:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p style="font-size: large"> 
        Some paragraph text 
        <span><pre style="display:inline">some span text</pre></span> 
        additional paragraph text that continues ...
    </p>

  </body>
</html>
```

So this is just a paragraph that contains some preformatted text in the middle. The problem that I am having is that both Opera and Chrome don't display this the way I expect. Specifically they close the paragraph tag before the span and force a new line. WTH?!

Using chromes HTML inspection options it shows that the `<p>` tag is being closed and an empty `<span></span>` inserted instead of enclosing the `<pre>`. If the span is removed chrome still closes the `<p>` tag, forcing a newline.

I need to have the following tag structure display without any newlines being forced `<p><span><pre><code></code></pre></span></p>`. Is this at all possible or is there another option or workaround?

EDIT:
I'm locked into having the `<pre>` tag as it is part of a syntax highlighting plugin for wordpress.

NOTE:
I think the best piece of advice here is to validate your HTML. A lot of the problems I was having was because of invalid HTML that was being handled gracefully by some browsers and not gracefully by others. Validating means you have a clean slate to work from.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Get rid of the `pre` tag altogether, and just give your `span` `style="white-space:pre"`. See [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_text_white-space.asp) for a description of other `white-space` options.

`<pre>` is basically saying `<div style="white-space:pre">`; what you want is `<span style="white-space:pre">`.

Comment: Isn't the main thing that `<pre>` does use `font-family: monospace;`? A span like yours does not look like a programming font at all.

Answer (score 6):

Paragraph tags cannot contain block-level elements:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1

`pre` is a block level element.

You could instead set the CSS style `white-space: pre` on your span if you desired to have `pre`-like behavior in an inline element.

Answer (score 1):

`pre` is a block level element, it isn't allowed to be inside a `span` if memory serves right.

You can find out by validating your HTML.

Comment: problem remains if the span tag is removed