# Paragraph tags necessary with header tags in HTML?

Tags: html, paragraph, html-heading

I am starting to learn HTML and in the lesson I am on it tells me to include text in the body with `<p>` paragraph tags. However, in a different section, it just tells me to put some text between `<h1>` tags and the result seems to be the same. Are `<p>` tags necessary to include in between heading tags?

Comment: Your question makes it appear as though they are requesting you nest <p> tags within an <h1> tag. This should not be done. Headings should be encapsulated with <h1> tags and paragraphs should be separate from your headings in their own tags.

Comment: You may want to reconsider what the accepted answer is. The one you accepted is wrong. Please let it fall to the bottom.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

In HTML you can have text in many ways even without anything on the HTML, not even the `<!DOCTYPE>` tag!

The `<p></p>` is just a way of design to the HTML that includes a certain font and size.

So technically, you CAN have `<p></p>` within a `<h1></h1>` tag but it's not really needed, it make a bit of difference though.

```
<p>
    <h1>
        This is Possible
    </h1>
</p>

<h1>
    <p>
        This is Possible
    </p>
</h1>

<p>
    This is Possible
</p>

<h1>
    This is Possible
</h1>
```

Comment: -1 This is not true. According to the DTD in HTML 4 and HTML 5 content models, the `p` element cannot be used inside `h1` and it cannot contain `h1` either.

Comment: Really? I've used it like this before with working solutions, surely it wasn't the best work I've done, but it works nonetheless.

**EDIT**
Just checked, It works, it's bad to do, but it works :)

Comment: When seeking HTML wisdom, always consult the spec. You’re not writing HTML when it does not conform to the spec, it’s just HTML-like. Browsers accept many things that are utterly wrong. The browser of your choice is not the only HTML processor in the whole world and some of the others may not accept the same erroneous HTML. (BTW, please use `@Palec` in your comment if you want to reply to my comments. See [How do comment @replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/238706) on Meta.)

Answer (score 3):

## Direct answer

No, the `<p>` is not necessary inside heading. Moreover, it must not be used there!

According to both the [HTML 4 DTD](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html#heading) and [HTML 5 content models](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#content-models), the `p` element cannot be used inside `h1` and it cannot contain `h1` either.

## References to specs

In HTML 4, [`p` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/text.html#edef-P) is defined as block-level and can contain only inline elements, the same holds for [`h1` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#edef-H1).

In HTML 5 [`p` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element) can be used in contexts where [flow content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#flow-content) is expected and can contain [phrasing content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content). The same holds for [`h1` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-h1,-h2,-h3,-h4,-h5,-and-h6-elements) again.

## Text

Other answers mentioned “free text” – paragraph text not marked up a `p` element contents. [Text](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#text-content) is categorized as both phrasing content and flow content in HTML 5 and it’s nothing really special. With HTML 4 I am not sure about this and I suspect that the spec does not say much about it.

Being flow content means that text can be directly embedded in [`body`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-body-element) as its content model is flow content. In fact, text can be embedded virtually anywhere. Using `p` elements is necessary for styling and paragraph breaks as any sequence of whitespace normally collapses into one before being displayed. But in some simple cases `p` need not be used, e.g. when the whole document is just a heading and one paragraph:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Really minimalistic HTML 5 example</title>
<h1>Really minimalistic HTML 5 example</h1>
And that’s all, folks!
```

Looking for `html`, `head` and `body` tags? They are [omitted](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#optional-tags); the elements still exist, though. But there is no `p` element. You can verify that in Firebug or by applying styles to `body` and `p`. If you want “And that’s all, folks!” to be a real `p` paragraph, just place `<p>` before “And”. (Closing tag `</p>` can be omitted.)

## How to think about HTML

As many people offer misleading advice on HTML, I want to point you in the right direction, as far as HTML understanding is concerned.

Element is not a tag. Element is a unit of document structure. Tag is a string that represents element in document source code. Most elements need two tags (opening and closing one) to represent them. E.g. `p` element is usually represented by `<p>` opening tag, `</p>` closing tag and the text between those two. The opening tag can also be e.g. `<p style="color: red">` – a different tag for the same element. Opening tag lists element’s attributes (`style` attribute in this case).

HTML is used to mark up structure of a document. You can completely ignore that browsers can somehow display `h1` in big bold font, with big margins. CSS takes care of elements’ presentation. JS takes care of element’s behavior.

The important thing on `h1` is it is a level 1 heading. It has this *meaning*, these *semantics*. `p`, on the other hand, is paragraph (approximately; for details see [my question on paragraphs in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20156262/2157640)). It is natural that headings and paragraphs are two distinct components of a document and that they are used independently one of the other. Using elements properly, respecting their defined semantics, is necessary for pretty display with styles switched off, SEO, browsing with screen readers and overall accessibility.

Answer (score 1):

h1 through h6 are header tags p is a paragraph tag.  will by default in most browsers display larger unless a reset of sorts is applied to it.

```
 <html>
<head>
<title>Hello World</title> 
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello World</h1> 
<p>Some Text</p>

</body>
</head>
```

here is a jsfiddle so you can see http://jsfiddle.net/snymax/93TSp/
*Edit* http://jsfiddle.net/snymax/93TSp/1/ displays h1 - h6 p and free text.

Answer (score 1):

Many of the HTML tags have some special meaning in terms of their display.
**Block Level** and **Inline Level**. Block level elements are semantically defined t start with a new line. Inline elements can share space within the same line. `<h1>` and `<p>` both are block level elements. General meaning of `<h1>` is a heading. A bolder, bigger text. `<p>` tag used to put large text. say a description of some thing. You are suggested to use them according to their meanings. `<span>` is an example of an **inline element**. You should judge how to use them according to your requirement. The general idiom is you should only put **Block level** (and inline ones) in a block level element only and not in an **Inline element**. In a stricter note, some parsing environments other than browser ( like small device publishing formats ) throw errors if you do such things.

That said, it is all your will how you include them.

For an advanced understanding : [Mozilla's trusted documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Block-level_elements)

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not - you can surround text with `<h1>` without `<p>`s.

Maybe you've been using some library that has a CSS rule that affects `h1 p`

Answer (score 0):

Nope.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1> My header </h1>
<p> some paragraph </p>
FREE TEXT..  Doesn't need any tags... 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

No

are not necessary but can clean your displayed text.

```
<h1> its a header </h1>
<p> its a paragraph of text under that specific header</p>
```

> and the result seems to be the same
>   No it isn't!