# Should I use <aside> for subtitles?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

**By "subtitles", I mean the literary definition: a secondary title beneath a title, such as the "A New Hope" part of "Star Wars".** If you're still confused, see Wikipedia's article, *[Software (titling)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtitle_%28titling%29)*.

I am transferring a document to HTML. In this, there is a title (I'm using an `h1` for this), its subtitle, and body content (I'm using `p`s for these). I initially considered doing this as a `small` within the `h1`, separated by a `br`. However, knowing HTML5, I also considered `aside`. Bootstrap recommends I use a `p class="lead"`, but I don't like the idea of it semantically being exactly as inportant as the rest of the article. **What element best represents a subtitle in HTML5?**

Comment: http://html5doctor.com/howto-subheadings/

Comment: @dave are you saying there is no definitive answer?

Comment: I would never use aside for something such as a subtitle. In my opinion (not sure what the spec has to say about this) an aside should be used for content of itself that only marginally or not at all relates to the main content of the page. Think of how Wordpress handles widgets (for instance "recent posts"): they are put in an aside. dave's example shows that it all depends on the case at hand. Personally, I often use a span inside the heading if it is quite short, and a seperate "p" if it is a full line of text or more. If the latter, wrap the "h"and the paragraph inside a `header` element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`aside` is a [sectioning element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#sectioning-content-0). I don't think it's appropriate to use it as a subheading element, since a subheading is just that, and not an entire section of content in itself. Furthermore, an `aside` can (and often does) itself contain other heading elements.

`p` is actually a pretty reasonable option, provided that you group that `p` and the `h1` that it accompanies within a `header` element, like so:

```
<header>
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>Subtitle</p>
</header>
```

As far as HTML is concerned, [a paragraph is just a self-contained unit of textual content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20156262/list-or-longer-code-snippet-inside-paragraph/20158687#20158687). It doesn't *have* to represent a paragraph of text in writing. If you are really concerned about its semantics though, feel free to replace it with a `div` or a `span` and/or use an appropriate class name.

HTML5 itself doesn't really provide much more of a solution for marking up subtitles, unfortunately, but I would say that `aside` is *not* the element to use.

Comment: I have always felt that a `div` is not a preferable element to contain plain text (unmarked by for instance paragraph tags). Yet again, I have no source to back me up, so it is a completely subjective thought. I tend to use divs as little as possible in HTML5. The new HTML5 elements (section, header, article, aside, nav) for a semantic document division and p, span, a for text containers. Divs are only needed in some cases where no other element of the former group is semantically relevant. Again, this is a personal opinion - but it helps to make your mark-up consistent across your work.

Comment: @Bram Vanroy: Indeed +1 - I'm mainly suggesting it only as a last resort should the author not deem something like `p` appropriate.

Comment: What about `small`, then...?

Comment: +1 Correct answer. I’d only add this link to the HTML5 (CR) spec: [Subheadings, subtitles, alternative titles and taglines](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140204/common-idioms.html#sub-head).

Comment: @Supuhstar: Well, I happen to use `small` on my landing page if that means anything :)