# How do I use pure CSS to select all children of some specified element？

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Say I have an HTML like:

```
<p>
  <label>Label</label>
  <input type="file" />
  <div>test div</div>
</p>
```

I want to select the `label`, `input` and `div` who are the child of the `p` tag, how can I select them all in one time? I don't want to be more specific because they might change.

Thanks,

Comment: `p > *` should select all immediate children, and `p *` should select all decendents.

Comment: I don't think it's semantically correct to have form elements in a p tag...

Comment: @Rafael any doc/reference for this? thanks for pointing out!

Comment: There might be documentation stating this but let's take a logical approach.  A p tag, for paragraphs has form elements inside it?

Comment: @Rafael: There's absolutely nothing wrong with putting input elements in p elements. You'll find *tons* of examples in the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html). As for "logical", the HTML spec actually recommends [not worrying about it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20156262/list-or-longer-code-snippet-inside-paragraph/20158687#20158687).

Comment: @BoltClock hmm very interesting.  Thanks for the articles.  I won't be doing it in my code although it is permitted.

Answer (score 2):

for do this you need add a class to `<p>` beacuase see below pic:
[image]

I do this by below css :

```css
p.para *,p.para + div{
    background: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<p class="para" >
  <label>Label</label>
  <input type="file" />
  <div>test div</div>
</p>
<div>ddd</div>
```

Comment: Your code is a mess. There are stray `}`s all over the place, the whitespace is horribly inconsistent, and I'm not sure why there is a `p +div` selector.

Answer (score 2):

If this is for a specific page the `p *` would just do fine.

However, if you have this rule in your main css file which is imported in all html files then `p *` would be a problem since it will update all nested elements in a `<p>` tag.

So its better to use individual rules in css file