# Correct HTML for multi-paragraph quotes

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I have text written like so:

> "Something something," he said. "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ne natum
>   elitr his, usu ex dictas everti, utamur reformidans ad vis. Eam
>   dissentiet deterruisset an, vis cu nullam lobortis. Doming inimicus eu
>   nec, laudem audire ceteros cu vis, et per eligendi splendide. Ne
>   legere tacimates instructior qui. Te vis dicat iudico integre, ex est
>   prima constituam consequuntur. Vix sanctus voluptaria ei, usu ornatus
>   iracundia ne, nam nulla iudico no. Duo ei labores nusquam.
>
> "In harum docendi fuisset vis. Meis constituam ea quo. Ei vim prima
>   liber officiis. Ad modo tota augue est, fugit soleat blandit eos ex."

The text follows an annoying typographical rule for multi-paragraph quotes: a quote which spans a paragraph doesn't have an end quote at the end of each internal paragraph, but it has an extra one at the start of each internal paragraph. HTML5 doesn't allow `<p>` elements inside `<q>`elements, but this situation is worse: the second quote doesn't even include all of the paragraph, so even if it did (or if I used, say, `<div class=quote>`) I can't see a way to mark this up without mis-aligned elements.

(Of course I could just embed quotation marks rather than use `<q>`, but I'm looking for thoughts on the best way to do this.)

Comment: add a `<br />`?

Comment: if you need your text to follow a predefined pattern you can use <pre> which will format the text exactly as it is typed. Another useful thing to note is that, as far as memory serves, ' ' and " " are equivalent except that ' ' makes nesting " " easier.

Comment: I'm more concerned with getting the semantics right -- I can always use CSS to make it look pretty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The previous answer (redefining `quotes: '\201c' '\201d' '\2018' '\2019';`) works, but it overrides the user's locale and forces American style quotation marks.

Instead, this:

```
<style>
    q.continued::after { font-size: 0; }
</style>
…
<p>
    I replied, <q class="continued">Blah blah blah.</q>
</p>
<p>
    <q class="continued">And not only that!</q>
</p>
<p>
    <q>So there!</q>, and left the room.
</p>
```

Produces:

```
I replied, ”Blah blah blah.

”And not only that

”So there!”, and left the room.
```

Which should work correctly with any locale's quotation characters.

---

Note that `display:none` would be better, but it doesn't work.
The browser (Chrome at least) notices that the closing quote is missing and switches to the alternate quote mark for the following paragraphs.

Comment: That’s an elegant use of simple CSS.

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest way to do this is indeed with quotation marks; they are just as semantically appropriate as using the `<q>` element. From the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-q-element):

> The use of `q` elements to mark up quotations is entirely optional; using explicit quotation punctuation without `q` elements is just as correct.

> **Code Example:**
>
> In the following example, quotation marks are used instead of the `q` element:
>
> ```
> <p>His best argument was ❝I disagree❞, which
> I thought was laughable.</p>
> ```

Having said that, you *can* still do this using `<div class=quote>` to mark the start and end of a multi-paragraph quotation as you've suggested, coupled with the following CSS:

```css
q {
  quotes: '\201c' '\201d' '\2018' '\2019';
}

.quote > p:not(:last-of-type) > q:last-child {
  quotes: '\201c' '' '\2018' '';
}
```

```html
<div class=quote>
  <p><q>Something something,</q> he said. <q>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
     ne natum elitr his, usu ex dictas everti, utamur reformidans ad vis.
     Eam dissentiet deterruisset an, vis cu nullam lobortis. Doming
     inimicus eu nec, laudem audire ceteros cu vis, et per eligendi
     splendide. Ne legere tacimates instructior qui. Te vis dicat iudico
     integre, ex est prima constituam consequuntur. Vix sanctus voluptaria
     ei, usu ornatus iracundia ne, nam nulla iudico no. Duo ei labores
     nusquam.</q></p>

  <p><q>In harum docendi fuisset vis. Meis constituam ea quo. Ei vim prima
     liber officiis. Ad modo tota augue est, fugit soleat blandit eos ex.</q></p>
</div>
```

But this requires using `<div class=quote>` wherever necessary in the first place. Granted, as it's just a div, it doesn't set the text containing the quotation apart from the rest of the prose (in contrast, a blockquote would be entirely inappropriate for this reason), or otherwise change the meaning of the text, but it's still not as clean as you might like. It does however work regardless of whether that second paragraph has been represented in its entirety or if there is more text following the closing quotation mark — or indeed, even if the second paragraph contains both the end of one quotation and the start of another (just move your `</div>` end tag to where the second quotation ends).

You'll notice in the above snippet that the `<q>` elements themselves are split by paragraph; this is [perfectly normal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20156262/list-or-longer-code-snippet-inside-paragraph/20158687#20158687) since `<q>` is a phrasing element and therefore, as you've stated, cannot span multiple flow elements. But if you really are worried that the split `<q>` elements will be seen (particularly by AT) as two separate quotations altogether, you can either associate them using a class or a custom data attribute, or just go with quotation marks which are much simpler and will convey the meaning of the text just as effectively.

Comment: `quotes: '\201c' '\201d' '\2018' '\2019';` assumes that I want the American style `*He said "this is called a 'thingy'".*` when nesting.  The main reason for using `<q>` is so that the correct convention will be used for the locale of the reader, and the proposed solution disables that ability.  Is there any way to override only the second and fourth values and leave the first and third as the local default?

Comment: @Ray Butterworth: I see you've figured that out on your own, so I've added a vote to your answer. Thanks for the feedback!