# CSS properties don’t work for paragraphs with pre elements inside

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pre

I have a paragraph that contains a `<pre>` element and some text, like the following:

```
<p class="par1">
     <pre>
           this is second paragraph
           ok
           ok
     </pre>
     These text are inside the paragraph must be RED
</p>
```

And I have used the following code to change the background color of the paragraph, but it doesn’t affect the paragraph and I don’t know why.

```
<style>
     .par1{
           background-color:red;
           color:green;
     }
</style>
```

Here’s the whole code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test id and class attribute</title>
  <style>
    .par1 {
      background-color: red;
      color: green;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="div1">
    Some text
    <h1>An important heading</h1>
    <p class="par1">
      <pre>
          this is second paragraph
          ok
          ok
      </pre>
      This text is inside the paragraph and it must be red.
    </p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I know that if I use the class of the div `.div1`, it works fine, but I want to know why the first one doesn’t work.

```
.div1{
    background-color:red;
    color:green;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [W3c specs say](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element), you can't have a `pre` inside a `p`

> ### **4.4.1 The `p` element**
>
> **Content model:**
>
> Phrasing content.

Where [Phrasing Content](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content-1) is:

> Phrasing content is the text of the document, as well as elements that
>   mark up that text at the intra-paragraph level. Runs of phrasing
>   content form paragraphs.
>
> `a`
>      `abbr`
>      `area` (if it is a descendant of a `map` element)
>      `audio`
>      `b`
>      `bdi`
>      `bdo`
>      `br`
>      `button`
>      `canvas`
>      `cite`
>      `code`
>      `data`
>      `datalist`
>      `del`
>      `dfn`
>      `em`
>      `embed`
>      `i`
>      `iframe`
>      `img`
>      `input`
>      `ins`
>      `kbd`
>      `keygen`
>      `label`
>      `map`
>      `mark`
>      `math`
>      `meter`
>      `noscript`
>      `object`
>      `output`
>      `progress`
>      `q`
>      `ruby`
>      `s`
>      `samp`
>      `script`
>      `select`
>      `small`
>      `span`
>      `strong`
>      `sub`
>      `sup`
>      `svg`
>      `template`
>      `textarea`
>      `time`
>      `u`
>      `var`
>      `video`
>      `wbr`

you can use instead a `span` and setting it as `display:block` which will make it a block level element

```css
.par1 {
  background-color: red;
  color: green;
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  Some text
  <h1>An important heading</h1>
  <span class="par1">
    <pre>
      this is second paragraph
       ok
       ok
    </pre>
    These text are inside the paragraph must be RED
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

as @dippas said, it's about the `<pre>`-tag inside a `<p>`-tag

`<p>`-tags can not contain block-level elements. as `<pre>` is a block-level element, browsers seem to close the `<p>`-tag, before the `<pre>`-tag opens (see your browser inspector). thus the styles on `<p>` could not be inherited by the `<pre>`-tag

for a good discussion with helpful hints, see:

[<pre> tag making browsers close paragraphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508415/pre-tag-making-browsers-close-paragraphs)

EDIT:

In the W3C specs, it is said that "A paragraph is typically a run of phrasing content (...)".

https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#paragraphs

Comment: can we say "a block level elements cannot contain another block level element"?

Comment: no, not really. <header>s contain <nav> elements, <aside>s may contain <article>s. so, it's not that easy. you could say that inline-elements should not contain block elements. and that inline elements and inline-block elements should be used, when it is about to design floating content (like all these letters are) ...vertical-align plays a role here too. so... it's a little more complicated. but a solid knowledge of the different display styles and their implications was a big win to me. hope, that gave you an idea.. honestly.. the <pre>-thing was knew to me too and it seems weirdo :-)